# Animación en cambio de componentes con operador ternario

Tags: reactjs, animación

Estoy usando react con redux, changeData hace un fetch y alterna el estado de data.iSaveIt entre false o true entonces el icono cambia.
Como puedo hacer para que haya una animación cuando se cambia el icono

```
  <div
    className="cursor-pointer"
    onClick={() => {
      dispatch(
        changeData(/*...*/) //...
      );
    }}
  >
    {!data?.iSaveIt ? (
      <SaveIcon className="h-6 sm:h-7" />
    ) : (
      <SaveIconFill className="h-6 sm:h-7" />
    )}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías envolver los iconos con el operador ternario en un componente nuevo llamemosle 'IconContainer' donde pasarías 'isSaveIt' como prop, dentro de él declararías un useEffect() pasando como dependencia dicho prop que al cambiar de estado realizaría la animación, la lógica de la animación la tendrias en el propio componente, dentro del useEffect:

```
import {AiFillSave, AiOutlineSave} from "react-icons/ai";
import '../styles/styles.css'
import { useEffect } from "react";

const animateConfig = [ // datos para element.animate()
  [
    { opacity: '0', transform: 'scale(0.2)' }, 
    { opacity: '70', transform: 'scale(0.7)' }, 
    { opacity: '100', transform: 'scale(1)' }
  ], { duration: 300 }
]

export default function IconContainer({isSaved}){ // <- recibimos la prop
  useEffect(() => {
    let target;
    target = document.getElementById('saveicon') // dependiendo del valor de la prop ejecutamos la animacion sobre un icono o sobre el otro
    if(!isSaved) target = document.getElementById('saveoutlineicon')
    target.animate(...animateConfig) // pasamos las opciones de animacion, mediante el spread operator
  }
  ,[isSaved]) // pasamos la prop como dependencia del useEffect, esto ejecutara esta funcion por cada renderizado

  return(
    <div className="iconContainer">
      {isSaved ? <AiFillSave id="saveicon"></AiFillSave> : <AiOutlineSave id="saveoutlineicon"></AiOutlineSave>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Debes agregar un id que identifique cada icono para usar document.getElementById(), ahora lo último seria agregar el nuevo IconContainer como hijo de tu div 'cursor-pointer':

```
  return (
    <div
      className="cursor-pointer"
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch(
          changeData(/*...*/) //...
        );
      }}
    >
      <IconContainer isSaved={isSaved}></IconContainer>
    </div>
  );
```

Cabe mencionar que si agregas más de 1 componente de ese tipo deberás modificar ligeramente el código, ya que los id's se repetirían.